How to set up time-constrained user login into a web app via Google OAuth?
I would like to provide a '7 day trial' period for a web app. Google OAuth is set up as the sole Login method to the web app. I'm wondering how I can use Google OAuth to grant access and proceed to the web app and deny access after a certain time interval (e.g. 7 days after first sign in)?
I set up Google OAuth but could not find any settings in the Google Cloud console under 'APIs & Services'.
